# Why does the value of a variable changes inside jQuery $.each method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to rename my input fields nested in a div called `property-container`. User can create multiple `property-container`. Each time the user creates this div I want to rename the input fields accordingly. Here is my form generated dynamically

```
<div class="property-container">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][id]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][name]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][stations][1][id]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][stations][1][name]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][stations][1][price]">
</div>
```

This is how I rename them

```
stationFieldsNames:function(station_container, systemNumber){
        station_container.find('.property-container').each(function(i, s){
            var hidden = $('.property-container input[type=hidden]:first');
            var system_id = station_container.index('div');
            $(this).append('SCI inside '+system_id);
            hidden.attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][id]');
            hidden.next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][name]');
            hidden.next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+i+'][id]');
            hidden.next().next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+i+'][name]');
            hidden.next().next().next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+i+'][price]');
        });
```

As you see I print out the `system_id` inside the `$.each()` method and I see the number is correct each time but the value in the field name is not the same. If the `system_id` let's say 44 the field name is 1. I don't understand why it does this.

Comment: Can we see an example of your HTML?  There could be many reasons why `.index` is not returning whaty ou want

Comment: `.next().next().next().next()` ~ really?

Comment: @Sparky Do you have suggestion to make it better?

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was selecting the first input. This how it is working now.
`var container = $(this);
 var hidden = container.find('input[type="hidden"]:first');`
The rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
station_container.find('.property-container').each(function(i, s){
    var hidden = $('input[type=hidden]:first', this);
    var system_id = $(this).index();
    $(this).append('SCI inside '+system_id);
    hidden.attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][id]');
    hidden.next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][name]');
    hidden.next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+i+'][id]');
    hidden.next().next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+i+'][name]');
    hidden.next().next().next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+i+'][price]');
});
```

Comment: I fixed it above. Thanks. How can this be improved? I don't like using next() so many times. Any advice?